# insert from select misses some rows - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, database-concurrency

We have a table with around 7M records with type `ferrari` and want to do a schema migration. We used this script

```
insert into new_car id, name, type, colorType
   select id, name, type, 'red' 
   from old_car 
   where type = 'ferrari' 
   order by id asc
```

The script took around 50 minutes to execute and after it got complete we realised that the `new_car` table have 2M less records than `old_car` table.
While the script was executing the `old_car` table still got inserts, updates and etc concurrently.

Does this concurrency may cause some sort of problem? What are the possible cause of the lack of ~2M rows? (the `old_car` table didn't got 2M deletes while the query was running, maybe something like 100 or 200 deletes)

Comment: The statement inserted the rows that were in `old_car` at the moment the statement started. While the statement is running it does not see changes to the table.

Comment: welll you only insert `'ferrari'` cars, not all cars ... are you surprise you only insert 5 millions? I would say that is too much unless you are in Dubai. BTW if you query took 50 minutes you probably doesnt have one index for `type` show us `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the table had 7M records with type `ferrari`, I already fixed it in the question.
@a_horse_with_no_name the `old_car` table didn't had 2M deletes, just a few (100 or 200).

My concern is not about the time took by the execution. I'm worried about the missing rows.

Comment: You cant reference two user on the same comment, You should create seperated comment so each user get a notification. As @horse say at the moment of you query start, db create a snapshot of the table, so things happening on the db shouldnt affect the result.

Comment: Try two things... `CREATE TABLE test_count as SELECT count(*) FROM old_cars where type= 'ferrari'` and then `CREATE TABLE test_create as SELECT * FROM old_cars where type= 'ferrari'` and let me know the results

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the problem is that only a set of the rows that match the where clause were migrated. There was no problem on table creation or from records deleted from old table.

Comment: I know, but you are inserting on `new_car`. I want to be sure the target table isnt a factor, like a hidden trigger. Also validate the number of source and result rows. That is call eat the elephant. Try to eat small pieces.

Comment: Also you can create a copy of old_car to remove the concurrence from the equation.  `CREATE TABLE old_car_2 AS SELECT * FROM old_car`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza there is no triggers on new table.

Comment: I just trying to help. But you need give us something else